# Changing the way my program accepts files will create this error from GSON: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $?

Tags: java, gson, system-properties

There's been a lot of questions asked about this topic but this question is different because the way I define a certain variable is what determines whether or not this error is thrown.

Basically, I have the below JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "appiumVersion":"1.8.1",
    "buildTag": "build-0",
    "newCommandTimeout": "30",
    "deviceName":"Samsung Galaxy S9 WQHD GoogleAPI Emulator",
    "deviceOrientation":"portrait",
    "browserName":"",
    "platformName":"Android",
    "platformVersion":"7.1",
    "app":"sauce-storage:ApiDemos-debug.apk"
  },
  {
    "appiumVersion":"1.8.1",
    "buildTag": "build-0",
    "newCommandTimeout": "30",
    "deviceName":"Samsung Galaxy S9 WQHD GoogleAPI Emulator",
    "deviceOrientation":"portrait",
    "browserName":"",
    "platformName":"Android",
    "platformVersion":"7.0",
    "app":"sauce-storage:ApiDemos-debug.apk"
  }
]
```

I am using GSON to parse it and this is the code for it:

```
File capsJsonFile = new File(capsFilePath);
Reader capsReader = null;

try {
    capsReader = new FileReader(capsJsonFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Gson gsonCapsJsonArr = new Gson();

JsonObject[] capsJsonArr = gsonCapsJsonArr.fromJson(capsReader,  JsonObject[].class);
```

Then, I have another program that calls the above code:

```
capsFile = "C:\\Users\\exue\\IdeaProjects\\j-mobile\\tests\\src\\test\\resources\\capsJsonArray.json";
AutomationFramework.setCapsFilePath(capsFile);
```

And this code sets the "capsFilePath" variable equal to "capsFile".

What's weird is that if I write the program like this I have no error. But, I want to pass this capsFile string in as a system property through the maven-surefire-plugin that I am using to run this program, like so:

```
capsFile = System.getProperty("capsFile");
AutomationFramework.setCapsFilePath(capsFile);
```

I configured the plugin to look like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
            <property>
                <name>capsFile</name>
                <value>C:\\Users\\exue\\IdeaProjects\\j-mobile\\tests\\src\\test\\resources\\cfgJsonFile.json</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Having written it like this, taking the file as a system property, I now get this error:

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:939)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:865)
        at com.transunion.qecop.automationframework.AutomationFramework.mobileDeviceDataProvider(AutomationFramework.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
... 19 more
```

But if I just hard-code the string, then this error does not occur. How could the way in which I feed in the file possibly cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this problem is that you are referring to two different JSON's

the one you are passing in string is **capsJsonArray.json**

whereas the one you are passing in maven is **cfgJsonFile.json**

I think the problem lies in json being refereed as it may be incorrect